# Simulating slow/lossy communication in java

Tags: java, performance, communication, simulation, tcpmon

I need to test a functionality internal to my company's server whose benefit is evident only when clients run slow (as of latency and packet loss). To that extent, I need to simulate clients on a slow and/or lossy connection (TCP/HTTP). I'm using a Mac, Mountain Lion, and ideally I'd need to run both server and client locally.

One approach I tried to pursue -- unsuccessfully -- was to get hold of some java APIs that allow me to build clients with slow connections. I know JMeter has got something called SlowSockets (or something similar), but I was looking for APIs more focused on slow-performing clients. Any ideas of useful APIs?

Another approach I tried consisted in using a proxy to act as a middleman between client and server. In that case, the proxy should provide functionalities for simulating slow links. I've tried Charles proxy (Mac) and Apache TCPMon, however I seem to miss something when I try to get them at work. With TCPMon, for instance, when I start it in 'Proxy' mode (which is the mode that offers the 'simulate slow link' functionality) I define port for the local proxy, but I can't see how to define the remote host and port. Something similar happens with Charles Proxy; I can set the local port in the Proxy settings, but I can't understand how to define the remote end of the proxy (in fact connections fail saying the remote server is not responding). Anyone having ideas what I'm doing wrong?

One further approach I have tried to pursue is by using lower-level (e.g. OS-based) means; in this case, I tried Apple's Network Link Conditioner. I switched it on and defined my slowness parameters, but when I ping I don't seem to see the expected RTT etc. I've got a feeling NLC has a tight relationship with XCode and iOS testing, anyone capable of putting it at work for testing other (e.g. Java) applications? I've also tried ipfw on Mac, however the manual says ipfw is now deprecated and I don't want to dedicate time to get to know a tool that won't be available soon.

Any idea/help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you already have the best answer; an adequate proxy gives you full control over the data being sent. perhaps you should rework your question to specifically ask about what proxy software to use and/or how to properly configure it.

Comment: Have you considered using a mocking framework? If your code is well isolated, this could help you mimick the behaviour you want.

Comment: @AlexLynch my first choice would really be an API I could use to build a configurable graphical tool, but a proxy is a good enough solution. Unfortunately I seem to miss something on how to put those proxies I've been using at work properly. Any experience with any of them?

Comment: @fge: I'm not sure how a mocking framework could help, but anyway that would likely involve an effort comparable to the one of building my own 'slow client framework', for which I've got no time. That's why a proxy seemed a good deal.

Comment: An HTTP proxy doesn't have a 'remote' host because it figures out the remote host from the incoming HTTP request (it's different every time: it doesn't make sense to configure the remote host)